# Issue with FormHelper Select Boxes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.2, formhelper

I have the following tables

```
articles (Article model)
- id
- topic_id

articles_topics (ArticleTopic model)
- id
```

When I am in the **ArticlesController add()** I successfully generate a select list of the different topics to choose from like so:

```
$this->set('topics', $this->Article->ArticleTopic->find('list'));
```

My articles **add.ctp** view displays a populated select list using the following code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('topic_id', array('empty' => 'Select a Topic'));
```

All good here. my issue is with other models such as Sidebar and SidebarLocation. These are linked properly.

The tables are

```
sidebars (Sidebar model)
- id
- sidebar_location_id

sidebars_locations (SidebarLocation model)
- id
```

I have tried setting in my **SidebarsController add()** the following

```
$this->set('sidebar_locations', $this->Sidebar->SidebarLocation->find('list'));
$this->set('sidebarlocations', $this->Sidebar->SidebarLocation->find('list'));
$this->set('locations', $this->Sidebar->SidebarLocation->find('list'));

// I have also used compact for this
```

However, the select list on sidebars **add.ctp** is not populating. IT IS NOT AN EMPTY ARRAY. If I print it, it works.

Again I am using the following code for the form.

```
echo $this->Form->input('sidebar_location_id', array('empty' => 'Select a Location'));
```

I know that the issue is because the column is titled "**sidebar_location_id**". It works if I rename this to "**location_id**" and rename the model **SidebarLocation.php** to **Location.php** but I cannot do this because there are multiple other models that have associated location-type models (ie: Company model is associated to CompanyLocation model using the foreign key company_location_id). I need these separate SidebarLocation and CompanyLocation models for the distinction.

**EDIT:** I guess to answer my own questions I can use in my form

```
echo $this->Form->input('sidebar_location_id', 
    array('type'=>'select','options'=> $sidebar_locations)
);
```

But I'm hoping if anyone knows a way I can continue to use JUST as I can with other models

```
echo $this->Form->input('sidebar_location_id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bowlerae,

You need to set your value from controller in below way:

```
$sidebarLocations = $this->Sidebar->SidebarLocation->find('list');
$this->set(compact('sidebarLocations'));
```

And in your CTP

```
echo $this->Form->input('sidebar_location_id');
```